# Unexpected use of try except on Python

Tags: python

I am learning python and I was trying to make a game like rooms type that only have questions.
I use python 2.7 on my ubuntu 14.04

There are two ways to finish the game and no dead end.

> bb_room->flats_room->brass_or_wood->parts->stavros

**or**

> bb_room->sharps_room->parts->stavros

I post the whole code and I have some questions:

**1st**

If I choose the first path when I get to `stavros` room and answer a number and prints to me the right answer, after I hit enter it asks me for

```
flats or sharps
```

which is the question if you answer the bb_room first question.

and when I choose the second path when I finish and hit enter like above it asks me for

```
brass or woodwind
```

I can not understand what is going on here!

**2nd**

Why when I am at `stavros` room again and give a letter instead of an integer it prints the

`Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again...`

`Press Enter to continue...`

And starts all over again. I did not use `try except` at this point (`stavros` room).

```
from sys import exit
import webbrowser
import os


def bb_room():
    print ("Play the Bb major \n(write the positions with spaces between)")
    positions=raw_input(prompt)
    positions_list=positions.split()
    try:
        positions_list=[int(a) for a in positions_list]
        if positions_list == [1,6,4,3,1,4,2,1]:
            print "\nYou right.."
            print "Do you like flats or sharps?"

            a=0
            while 1>a:
                fors=raw_input(prompt)
                fors=fors.lower()
                if fors=="flats":                   
                    flats_room()
                elif fors=="sharps":                    
                    sharps_room()
                else:
                    print "Choose flats or sharps"

        else:
            dead("You don't know the basics.")
    except ValueError:
        print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
        raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
        os.system('clear')
        start()

def flats_room():
    print ("\nHow many flats Db major has?")    
    flats=raw_input(prompt)
    flats=flats.lower()
    if flats=="5" or flats=='five':
        print "That's right!"
        brass_or_wood()
    else:
        dead("You should learn some music theory.")

def sharps_room():
    print ("\nHow many sharps E major has?")
    sharps=raw_input(prompt)
    sharps=sharps.lower()
    if sharps=="4" or sharps=='four':
        print "That's right!"
        parts()
    else:
        dead("You should learn some music theory.") 

def brass_or_wood():
    print ("\nWhat kind of instrument a trombone is?\nBrass or Windwood?")  
    a=0
    while 1>a:
        bow=raw_input(prompt)
        bow=bow.lower()
        if bow=="brass":
            print "That's right!"
            parts()
        elif bow=="windwood":
            webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2WH8mHJnhM",new=0,autoraise=True)
            dead("Go play some recorder!")      
        else:
            print "Choose Brass or Windwood!"

def parts():
    print ("\nHow many parts a trombone has?")  
    parts=raw_input(prompt)
    parts=parts.lower()
    if parts=="4" or parts=='four':
        print "That's right!"
        stavros()
    else:
        dead("You should learn some stuff about the bone.") 

def stavros():
    print ("\nYou meet Stavros at Politistiko and of course you are unprepared\nfor your lesson. How many points you lose?")    
    points=raw_input(prompt)
    points=int(points)
    if points > 0 and points <100:
        print ("You guessed right. %d is the right amount you deserve to loose" % points)           
    elif points < 0:
        print ("You can't lose a negative number cause you 'll add it!")            
    elif points >100:
        print ("Don't be so hard with yourself. Stavros is not a bad guy")          
    else:
        print ("You should put a number")

def start():
    print ("Welcome to the Trombone game.\n\n") 
    bb_room()

def dead(why):
    print why, "Start practising!"
    raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
    os.system('clear')
    start()

prompt="> "
start()
```

Comment: Irrelevant. If there's an exception handler anywhere in the call stack then it will be used.

Comment: To expand, `bb_room` has a `try` where you call `flats_room`, in which you call `brass_or_wood`, in which you call `parts`, in which you call `stavros`. Enter a non-integer and you'll go all the way back up to that `try`.

Comment: So you mean that wherever a `VallueError` occurs the except code will run? Why use `try` then?

Comment: No, it means that you _were_ in the `try` at that point. Python doesn't care if the `try` is a bit far away; it won't forget.

Comment: @trelozakinthinos Because you can narrowly focus it around like 2 lines of code where it will catch only certain exceptional conditions?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I get it. We post at the same time! Thank you for the answer! The 2nd question is answered. How can I accept it if it is only in comments?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Excuse me could you rephrase your question? I didn't get it. thank you.

Comment: @trelozakinthinos You had a `try` casting a very wide net, overseeing several lines of code, catching any of a particular kind of error in all those lines. You asked, "Why use `try` then?" Answer: Because it works a lot better if it has a narrower focus, having as few lines as possible in its block and preferably only one possible way the error it's catching can occur (unless it sensibly handles the other occurrences as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

`stavros` is called in `parts` which is called in `brass_or_wood`. In `brass_or_wood`, you have an infinite loop, with `a=0` and `while 1>a` (you can shorten that to simply `while 1:`, by the way). You never change `a`, so this will never end. As soon as `stavros` has finished running, the code will go back to where it was called in `parts`, which finishes running and goes back to where it was called in `brass_or_wood`. It then finishes that iteration of the loop and prompts for more input for `bow`. If you don't pick `'brass'` or `'windwood'` at that point, it'll go to the `else` block and remind you to pick brass or woodwind ("windwood"). Use `break` to break out of the loop:

```
while 1:
    bow=raw_input(prompt)
    bow=bow.lower()
    if bow=="brass":
        print "That's right!"
        parts()
        break
    elif bow=="windwood":
        dead("Go play some recorder!")
        break
    else:
        print "Choose Brass or Windwood!"
```

You should do this for any other similar loops in your program, as well.

Second:

`bb_room` has a `try` where you call `flats_room`, in which you call `brass_or_wood`, in which you call `parts`, in which you call `stavros`. Enter a non-integer and you'll go all the way back up to that `try`.

If you get a `ValueError` while in any of those - basically, anywhere in your program, since `bb_room` is called almost immediately - the exception will be passed upwards, looking for a handler. It will find that handler in `bb_room`'s `try..except` and produce the result you saw.

Comment: Thank you. I had not realize this concept of going back like this! Thank you also for the loop trick and the woodwind thing!